# Which dependencies should I inject?

Tags: dependency-injection

When using dependency injection which dependencies do you inject?

I have previously injected all dependencies but have found when doing TDD there are typically two types of dependency:

- Those which are genuine external dependencies which may change e.g. ProductRepository
- Those which exist purely for testability e.g. Part of the behaviour of the class that has been extracted and injected just for testability

One approach is to inject ALL dependencies like this

```
public ClassWithExternalDependency(IExternalDependency external,
    IExtractedForTestabilityDependency internal)
{
    // assign dependencies ...
}
```

but I've found this can cause dependency bloat in the DI registry.

Another approach is to hide the "testability dependency" like this

```
public ClassWithExternalDependency(IExternalDependency external)
    : this (external, new ConcreteClassOfInternalDependency())
{}

internal ClassWithExternalDependency(IExternalDependency external,
    IExtractedForTestabilityDependency internal)
{
    // assign dependencies ...
}
```

This is more effort but seems to make a lot more sense. The downside being not all objects are configured in the DI framework, thereby breaking a "best practice" that I've heard.

Which approach would you advocate and why?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're better off injecting all of your dependencies. If it starts to get a little unwieldy, that's probably an indication that you need to simplify things a bit or move the dependencies into another object. Feeling the "pain" of your design as you go can be really enlightening.

As for dependency bloat in the registry, you might consider using some sort of conventional binding technique, rather than registering each dependency by hand. Some IoC containers have  convention-based type-scanning bindings built into them. For example, here's part of a module I use in a Caliburn WPF application that uses Ninject:

```
public class AppModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IShellPresenter>().To<ShellPresenter>().InSingletonScope();

        BindAllResults();
        BindAllPresenters();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Automatically bind all presenters that haven't already been manually bound
    /// </summary>
    public void BindAllPresenters()
    {
        Type[] types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();

        IEnumerable<Type> presenterImplementors =
            from t in types
            where !t.IsInterface
            && t.Name.EndsWith("Presenter")
            select t;

            presenterImplementors.Run(
                implementationType =>
                    {
                        if (!Kernel.GetBindings(implementationType).Any())
                            Bind(implementationType).ToSelf();
                    });
    }
```

Even though I have dozens of results and presenters running around, I don't have to register them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly won't inject all dependencies, because were to stop? Do you want to inject your `string` dependencies? I only invert the dependencies that I need for unit testing. I want to stub my database (see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128640/how-to-remove-unit-of-work-functionality-from-repositories-using-ioc/4132186#4132186) for instance). I want to stub the sending of e-mail messages. I want to stub the system clock. I want to stub writing to the file system.

The thing about inverting as many dependencies as you can, even those that you don't need for testing, is that make unit testing a lot harder and the more you stub out the less you really test how the system really acts. This makes your tests much less reliable. It also complicates your DI configuration in the application root.

Comment: One of the benefits of inverting the dependencies IS to be able to test  units in isolation. I may extract a calculator class to test it in isolation but maybe it doesn't need injecting (see second code example). I couldn't test it in-situ as it would bloat the tests for the client of the calculator class.

Comment: Inject all injectables, new all newables. Without this distinction, DI would require all objects living for the full duration of the program. Newables, aka value types, represent inert data and optionally some associated transformative behaviors (i.e. methods that take in values and return new values). Injectables, aka service/business types, represent functionality and optionally some associated program state. Arguably, we also have I/O types to represent external state, e.g. File(). I/O types must be newable but should be created through abstract factories so they can be mocked for test.

Answer (score 0):

I would wire all my non-external dependencies by hand and 'register' only external dependencies. When I say non-external, I mean the objects which belong to my component and which were extracted out to interfaces just for the sake of single responsibility/testability I would never have any other implementations of such interfaces ever. External dependencies are stuff like DB connections, web services, interfaces which don't belong to my component. I would register them as interfaces because their implementations can be switched to stubbed ones for integration testing. Having a small number of components registered in a DI container makes the DI code easier to read and bloat free.