# Repository pattern with "modern" data access strategies

Tags: linq, entity-framework, repository-pattern

So I was searching the web looking for best practices when implementing the repository pattern with multiple data stores when I found my entire way of looking at the problem turned upside down.  Here's what I have...

My application is a BI tool pulling data from (as of now) four different databases.  Due to internal constraints, I am currently using LINQ-to-SQL for data access but require a design that will allow me to change to Entity Framework or NHibernate or the next data access du jour.  I also hold steadfast to decoupled layers in my apps using an IoC framework (Castle Windsor in this case).

As such, I've used the Repository pattern to abstract the actual data access code from my business layer.  As a result, my business object is coded against some I<Entity>Repository interface and the IoC Container is used to manage the actual implementation.  In this case, I would expect to have a concrete Linq<Entity>Repository that implements the interface using LINQ-to-SQL to do the work.  Later I could replace this with an EF<Entity>Repository with no changes required to my business layer.

Also, because I'm coding against the interface, I can easily mock the repository for unit testing purposes.

So the first question that I have as I begin coding the application is whether I should have one repository per DataContext or per entity (as I've typically done)?  Let's say one database contains Customers and Sales with the expected relationship.  Should I have a single OrderTrackingRepository with methods that work with both entities or have a separate CustomerRepository and a different SalesRepository?

Next, as a BI tool, the primary interface is for reporting, charting, etc and often will require a "mashup" of data across multiple sources.  For instance, the reality is that one database contains customer information while another handles sales information and a third holds other financial information but one of my requirements is to display aggregated information that spans all three.  Plus, I have to support dynamic filtering in the UI.  Obviously working directly against the LINQ-to-SQL or EF DataContext objects (Table<Entity>, for instance) will allow me to pretty much do anything.  What's the best approach to expose that same functionality to my business logic when abstracting the DAL with a repository interface?

This article: [link text](http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article122.aspx) indicates that EF4 has turned this approach around and that the repository is nothing more than an IQueryable returned from the EF DataContext which brings up a whole other set of questions.

But, I think I've rambled on enough...

**UPDATE** (Thanks, Steven!)

Okay, let me put a more tangible (for me, at least) example on the table and clarify a few points that will hopefully lead to an approach I can better wrap my head around.

While I understand what Steven has proposed, I have a team of developers I have to consider when implementing such things and I'm afraid they will get lost in the complexity (yes, a real problem here!).

So, let's remove any direct tie-in with Linq-to-Sql because I don't want a solution that is dependant upon the way L2S works - or even EF, for that matter. My intent has been to abstract away the data access technology being used so that I can change it as needed without requiring collateral changes to the consuming code in my business layer. I've accomplished this in the past by presenting the business layer with IRepository interfaces to work against. Perhaps these should have been named IUnitOfWork or, more to my liking, IDataService, but the goal is the same. These interfaces typically exposed methods such as Add, Remove, Contains and GetByKey, for example.

Here's my situation. I have three databases to work with. One is DB2 and contains all of the business information for a customer (franchise) such as their info and their Products, Orders, etc. Another, SQL Server database contains their financial history while a third SQL Server database contains application-specific information. The first two databases are shared by multiple applications.

Through my application, the customer may enter/upload their financial information for a given time period. When entered, I have to perform the following steps:

1.Validate the entered data against a set of static rules. For example, the data must contain a legitimate customer ID value (in the case of an upload). This requires a lookup in the DB2 database to verify that the supplied customer ID exists and is current.
2.Next I have to validate the data against a set of dynamic rules which are contained in the third (SQL Server) database. An example may be that a given value cannot exceed a certain percentage of another value.
3.Once validated, I persist the data to the second SQL Server database containing the financial data.
All the while, my code must have loosely-coupled dependencies so I may mock them in my unit tests.

As part of the analysis, I know that I have three distinct data stores to work with and about a half-dozen or so entities (at this time) that I am working with. In generic terms, I presume that I would have three DataContexts in my application, one per data store, with the entities exposed by the appropriate data context.

I could then create a separate I{repository|unit of work|service} for each entity that would be consumed by my business logic with a concrete implementation that knows which data context to use. But this seems to be a risky proposition as the number of entities increases, so does the number of individual repository|UoW|service types.

Then, take the case of my validation logic which works with multiple entities and, thereby, multiple data contexts. I'm not sure this is the most efficient way to do this.

The other requirement that I have yet to mention is on the reporting side where I will need to execute some complex queries on the data stores. As of right now, these queries will be limited to a single data store at a time, but the possibility is there that I might need to have the ability to mash data together from multiple sources.

Finally, I am considering the idea of pulling out all of the data access stuff for the first two (shared) databases into their own project and have been looking at WCF Data Services as a possible approach. This would give me the basis for a consistent approach for any application making use of this data.

How does this change your thinking?

Comment: "require a design that will allow me to change to Entity Framework or NHibernate or the next data access du jour" I've never read of anyone actually achieving this.  Furthermore, this seems like a bad goal.  Why? ORM's, EF & NHib & others, are considerably more than "data access," and they seem to tend to lead to infrastructure that accomplishes similar goals in devilishly different ways that will make it effectively impossible to simple switch implementation of your IRepository and carry on. Initiating and ending entity lifetimes, as well as change tracking, are a couple big immediate gotchya

Comment: I've actually done it several times over the years as data access & ORM technologies have evolved. Being able to change the technology used at one level without requiring changes to other parts of your application is far from a "bad goal". It is in fact a core principal of solid object-oriented practices - only making a change in one place. As far as NHibernate, EF et al being more than data access... Well, you can also use ADO.NET directly in an ASP.NET code-behind if you want the quick & dirty approach. But I prefer a layered, SOA architecture that is easy to maintain and expand for my apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128640/how-to-remove-unit-of-work-functionality-from-repositories-using-ioc/4132186#4132186). I think it shows a simplified model of what you want. `IQueryable<T>` is indeed our new Repository :-). `DataContext` and `ObjectContext` are our Unit of Work.

**UPDATE 2:**

**[Here is a blog post](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=84)** that describes the model you might be looking for.

**UPDATE 3**

It would be wise to hide the shared databases behind a service. This will solve several problems:

1. This will make the database private to the service, which makes it much easier to change the implementation when needed.
2. You can put the needed validation logic (for database 1) in that service and can create tests for that validation logic in that project.
3. Clients accessing that service can assume correctness of the service, and its validation logic.

The result of this is that your application will send data to the service to validate it. Call the service to fetch data. Query its own private database (database 3) and join the data of the three data source locally together. I've never been a fan of using cross-database or even cross-server (in your situation) database calls and letting the database join everything together. Transactions will be promoted to distributed-transactions and it's hard to predict how many data the servers will exchange.

When you abstract the shared databases behind the service, things get easier (at least from your application's point of view). Your application calls services it trusts which limits the amount of code in that application and the amount of tests. You still want to mock the calls to such a service, but that would be pretty easy. It should also solve the problem of validating over multiple data sources.

Validation is always a hard part. I'm very familiar with Validation Application block, and love it for it's flexibility. It isn't however an easy framework, but you might take a peek at what you can do with it. For instance, I've written several articles about integration with O/RM tools and [how to 'embed' a context](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=47) (context as in DataContext/Unit of Work) in Validation Application Block.

Comment: IQueryable is *so* not the new Repository. My experience is that LINQ Provider implementations are wildly different, meaning only the simplest of queries works across various ones. I won't even get into referencing child collections in LINQ queries. Then there's the whole debate of whether a generic repository is even a good thing at all (and when it is a good thing, then it's really not a "Repository" in any standard definition of the term, certainly not a DDD Repository). The two Context objects are EF only, certainly not UnitOfWork if you're using anything else.

Comment: I agree that the quality of LINQ providers varies (especially open source providers). The EF 3.5 provider wasn't that good at all, but happily things have changed in .NET 4.0. My experience is that EF and L2S both run many complex queries and not just simple ones. I find having a generic repository that implements `IQueryable` very suitable, but when you plan on moving from one O/RM to another, it is wise to have integration tests that can easily verify if the new provider can handle the LINQ statements (because unit tests won’t help you here).

Comment: Wow, this seems to be a lot of complexity.  I can tell that what I was considering a repository can be more accurately described as a unit of work under this approach.  I'll have to re-read the linked article again to wrap my head around the other layers of your solution.

Comment: I *mostly* agree with this answer, however my repository has Find, Add, Remove - that's it. Plus there is *one* repository per aggregate root, not one per ORM. And i agree with @Steven in the above comment - i wouldn't use this pattern for L2SQL/EF3.5, but EF4 is extremely mature and works really well with this patttern (esp with POCOs).

Comment: @RPM1984: While physically there is one rep. type, conceptually there is a rep. per entity. All duplicate functionality (Insert, Del, etc) moved to t generic type, entity specific behavior was moved to extension methods. From a user’s perspective, there really is one rep. per entity. The number of reps can come close to 'one per aggr. root'. In my project I didn't define all my reps. upfront. I define them as I go. There's one catch; This model does make it harder to override default fetching behavior to implement specific perf tuning, or at least, this is something I haven't had to deal with.

Comment: @SonOfPirate: For me it was the perfect way of using multiple data stores, while limiting code duplication and achieving testability. Of course you need to add layers of abstraction to get this work and layers of abstraction of course do increase complexity. But still, personally I find this model very pleasing and understandable. Perhaps you need to see a concrete sample of this model? I'll try to write a blog post about it this weekend.

Comment: @SonOfPirate: Please take a look at this blog post. It gives a detailed description how I achieved this: http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=84

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond, but I do appreciate the detailed explanation in your blog post. A couple quick follow-ups. First, why extension methods versus a strongly-typed subclass? And second, how would you handle an entity (in business object terms) that required data from two data contexts (e.g. part of the data is stored in a SQL Server db with the rest in a DB2 or Oracle db)?

Comment: @SonOfPirate: Splitting entities over multiple databases? That's an interesting question. Especially how this would influence your design. This is something I'm not familiar with. Try asking that here at SO.

Comment: Here's my (long) post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319966/design-for-multi-tenant-app-using-soa-uow-repository-datacontext-multiple-da

Comment: I have also done a lot of work in this area, and INITIALLY came to the same conclusion, however it is NOT a good solution. The point of the Repo is to abstract queries into discrete chinks of work. Exposing IQueryable is too adhoc and raises some issues later down the line:

Answer (score 4):

In your case I would recommend returning IEnummerables's for your data queries for the repo. I usually aggregate calls from multiple repo's through a service class that represents the domain problem and encapsulates my business logic. To keep it clean I try keep my repros focused on the domain problem. I liken my Datacontext to a repo, and extract an interface using a T4 template to make life easier for mocking. But there is nothing stopping you using a traditional repo that encapsulates your calls. Doing it this way will allow you to switch ORM's at any stage.

EDIT: IQueryable IS NOT THE ANSWER! :-)
I have also done a lot of work in this area, and INITIALLY came to the same conclusion, however it is NOT a good solution. The point of the Repo is to abstract queries into discrete chunks of work. Exposing IQueryable is too adhoc and raises some issues later down the line. You loose your ability to scale. You loose your ability to optimize queries (Lets say I want to move to a highly optimized stored proc). You loose your ability to use IoC for the repo to switch out data access layers (switch the project from SQL to Mongo). You loose your ability to provide effective data caching in the Repo (Which is a major strength in the Repo pattern). I would recommend taking a CLOSE look as to WHY we have a Repo pattern. It isn't simply an "ORM" mapping layer. What made this really clear to me was the CQRS pattern.

Further to this allowing the ad-hoc nature of IQueryable opens you to misfitting reuse of queries. It is GENERALLY not a good idea to reuse queries, since query to query you see slight deviations, which ends up with 2 byproducts: Queries become too broad and inefficient. Queries become riddled with unmaintainable IF THEN statements to cater for the deviations.

IQueryable is easy, but opens you up to an unmaintainable mess.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at my [IRepository pattern implementation using EF 4.0](http://mandeepjanjua.com/index.php/blog/implementing-repository-pattern-using-entity-framework-4-0).

My solution has the following features:

1. supports connections to multiple dbs
2. One repository per entity
3. Support for execution of queries
4. Unit of work pattern implementation
5. Support for validating entities using VAB guidance
6. Common operations are kept at base class level. High use of OOPS techniques for code re-usability and ease of maintenance.