# Generics with Entity Framework Repository

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, generics, repository-pattern

I am reletively new to Entity Framework and LINQ. I have the following code with returns a list of suppliers

```
    public class SupplierRepository
{
    private DataContext db = new DataContext();

    public IQueryable<Supplier> FindAllSupplier()
    {
        return db.Suppliers;
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I know you can use Generics with Linq and EF. so that the above code would look something like this...

```
    public class GenericRepository
{
    private DataContext db = new DataContext();

    public IQueryable<T> FindAll<T>()
    {
        return ...
    }
}
```

So that I can use it to return any type in my EF model, but I am not sure how to implement this. Can anyone advise please?

Comment: This [blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/seanfao/archive/2009/12/03/136680.aspx) post sums it up pretty neatly

Comment: That looks great, the only problem is what is the GetQuery Method they mention? I can't seem to get this to work when replicating the code.

Comment: Can you help with explaining where the GetQuery comes from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of returning an `IQueryable<T>` let your repository implement `IQueryable<T>` and instead of wrapping a `DataContext` inside the repository, wrap both the `DataContext` and the repositories inside a unit of work. Your repository can than look like this:

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IQueryable<T>
    where T : class
{
    private readonly IQueryable<T> query;

    protected Repository(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        this.query = query;
    }

    public Type ElementType
    {
        get { return this.query.ElementType; }
    }

    public Expression Expression
    {
        get { return this.query.Expression; }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get { return this.query.Provider; }
    }

    public abstract void InsertOnSubmit(T entity);

    public abstract void DeleteOnSubmit(T entity);

    ...
}
```

I use this approach to effectively hide my O/RM behind an abstraction, which allows me to unit test my applicationm while still allowing to use LINQ over my repositories *and* have the unit of work pattern.

You can read all about it here: [Faking your LINQ provider](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=84).

Comment: This is one of my first attempts at using Linq/EF so I am sorry to say some of that has gone over my head. Can you explain a little more or provide a simplier example please?

Comment: @suggy: I'm sorry about that. I agree that this is a bit advanced stuff, but certainly not over engineered. Keep in mind however, that the article describes a design that works with multiple domeain models; this might complicate things a bit. A earlier (and simpler) version can be found in this SO article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128640/how-to-remove-unit-of-work-functionality-from-repositories-using-ioc. Perhaps it is of some help.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I guess I have some reading to do!!

Comment: @suggy: If you have any questions after you're done reading, don't hesitate to contact me. I'll be happy to help you out.